# Select a single enq/deq interface from a vector in IO to connect to a module in Chisel3

Tags: scala, chisel

I have a module with a vector of Enq/Deq interfaces as IO. Internally, I instantiate a module with a single Enq/Deq interface. I want to be able to input an index that will select Enq/Deq input interfaces and connect it to my internal module.

The code:

```scala
class TopModule(busWidth: Int = 4, numberOfBuffers: Int = 4) extends Module {
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val enq = Vec(numberOfBuffers, Flipped(Decoupled(UInt(busWidth.W))))
        val deq = Vec(numberOfBuffers, Decoupled(UInt(busWidth.W)))
        val command = Input(UInt(2.W))
        val bufferSelect = Output(UInt(log2Ceil(numberOfBuffers).W))
    })

    val myModule = Module(new MyModule(busWidth, numberOfBuffers))

    myModule.io.bufferSelect <> io.bufferSelect
    myModule.io.command <> io.command

    for (i <- 0 until numberOfBuffers - 1) {
         when(myModule.io.bufferSelect === i.U) {
             myModule.io.enq <> io.enq(i)
             myModule.io.deq <> io.deq(i)
         }.otherwise {
            kvTransfer.io.enq <> io.enq(0)
            kvTransfer.io.deq <> io.deq(0)
         }
    }
}
```

When I try to run tests, it fails with the following error message:

```
firrtl.passes.PassExceptions: firrtl.passes.CheckInitialization$RefNotInitializedException:  : [module TopModule]  Reference io is not fully initialized.
[info]    : io.deq[0].bits <= mux(_T, myModule.io.deq.bits, VOID)
```

I have spent a couple of hours trying to `switch/is`, adding `.otherwise` to `when`, etc. but it didn't work.

When I add `.otherwise` with io.enq(0) and io.deq(0) I don't get error for zero index but still get the same errors for indexes 1 to 3.

Could you please help with the issue? Thank you.

Chisel version 3.5.4

Comment: Have you tried specifying a default connection for `io.enq(i)` and `io.deq(i)`?
You could modify the `when` statement in your `for` loop by adding a `.otherwise` clause in which case the pins will be assigned a `DontCare` value.

Comment: Yes (I think). I added io.enq(0) and io.deq(0) in `.otherwise` inside the loop. But then it will complain about connections from 1 to 3.

Comment: My suggestion was more like:
```
when(myModule.io.bufferSelect === i.U) {
             myModule.io.enq <> io.enq(i)
             myModule.io.deq <> io.deq(i)
         }.otherwise {
             io.enq(i) := DontCare
             io.deq(i) := DontCare
         }
```

Comment: I see. That reduced errors to only three. This is a good progress. The error I am getting now:

```
Reference not initialized
myModule.io.enq.bits <= mux(_T_3, io.enq[3].bits, mux(_T_2, io.enq[2].bits, mux(_T_1, io.enq[1].bits, mux(_T, io.enq[0].bits, VOID))))

myModule.io.enq.valid <= mux(_T_3, io.enq[3].valid, mux(_T_2, io.enq[2].valid, mux(_T_1, io.enq[1].valid, mux(_T, io.enq[0].valid, VOID))))

myModule.io.deq.ready <= mux(_T_3, io.deq[3].ready, mux(_T_2, io.deq[2].ready, mux(_T_1, io.deq[1].ready, mux(_T, io.deq[0].ready, VOID))))
```

Comment: I am not sure where the VOID comes from in Mux, considering all cases where covered.

Comment: Chisel cannot always prove that all cases where covered. Thus you could just assign a default value to these ports at the top of your module. Like: myModule.io.deq := DontCare ; myModule.io.enq := DontCare

Comment: It worked. `.otherwise` + top-level DontCare for myModule. Thank you. Can you please submit an answer so I can accept it?